Postgres 16.2 on windows, unable to load self signed certificate error. SSL error code 2147483653
I'm trying to implement ssl on a Windows 10 host running PostgreSQL 16.2.
I have downloaded and installed OpenSSL-Win64 (3.3.0).
I followed the instructions from
https://methoddev.com/blog/postgresql-windows-encrypted-connection-ssl
and created the root certificate and server certificate
I installed the root certificate in the local machine CA, and copied the files into the /data folder of Postgres
files
root.crt,
Server.crt,
Server.key

postgresql.conf excerpt
ssl = on
ssl_ca_file = 'root.crt'
ssl_cert_file = 'Server.crt'
#ssl_crl_file = ''
#ssl_crl_dir = ''
ssl_key_file = 'Server.key'
#ssl_ciphers = 'HIGH:MEDIUM:+3DES:!aNULL' # allowed SSL ciphers
#ssl_prefer_server_ciphers = on
#ssl_ecdh_curve = 'prime256v1'
#ssl_min_protocol_version = 'TLSv1.2'
#ssl_max_protocol_version = ''
#ssl_dh_params_file = ''
#ssl_passphrase_command = ''
#ssl_passphrase_command_supports_reload = off

When I try and start PostgreSQL it immediately stops with
FATAL:  could not load server certificate file "Server.crt": SSL error code 2147483653
I've tried changing the owner of the file to NETWORK SERVICE the id running PostgreSQL but this did not help.
I can read all of the key files as text.
Do I need to remove all access except administrator and NETWORK SERVICE (as many posts about ssl certificate issues on linux point out) or is this another problem?
